# Terminate the i18n key in fxml

Tags: internationalization, javafx-8, fxml

I would like to separate the internationalization key from normal text in a labeled javafx element using fxml. The element looks like this:

```
<Button text="%select..." onMouseClicked="#selectDataLocation" />
```

And the properties file contains the entry:

```
select=Select
```

The resulting text of the button should be `Select...`, but I get the exception `javafx.fxml.LoadException: Resource "select..." not found.`

Is there a way to terminate the internationalization key, so that the following text is interpreted as normal text?

Edit:
I'm aware that I could use something like this as a work around:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML private Button selectButton;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        selectButton.setText(selectButton.getText() + "...");
    }

}
```

But I think that this would be an overkill, just to add some dots to an internationalized string.